# Qt programming QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I am using `Qt` and `C++` to add some features to a freeware called: `EASYPAINT`.

I had to add a more intuitive method in which the users can see the actual width directly from the tool instead of changing numbers. ( just like in the new windows paint , where you can actually see the line thickness and not pixels.)

I am using a `QComboBox`. My question is (look at the code first), instead of having 20 (`penSizeList->addItem`), I know we can have `addItems`.... But what about the icon. for each `Item`, will I have to search for 20 different line `thickness.png` and add them? Or is there another method I can use?

And also, how can I get rid of the string in `addItem`, and only keep an image or icon in the `QComboBox`.

```
QComboBox *penSizeList = new QComboBox();
penSizeList->setIconSize(QSize(100,100));
penSizeList->setStatusTip("Pen Size");

QIcon ONEpxIcon(":/media/actions-icons/clear-gray.png");
QIcon THREEpxIcon(":/media/instruments-icons/canvas-lines1.png");

penSizeList->addItem(ONEpxIcon,"1px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"2px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"3px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"4px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"5px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"6px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"7px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"8px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"9px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"10px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"11px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"12px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"13px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"14px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"15px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"16px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"17px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"18px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"19px");
penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,"20px");

connect(penSizeList,SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(penValueChanged(int)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this in loop.

```
penSizeList->addItem(ONEpxIcon,"1px");
for(int i = 2; i < 21 ; i++)
{
    penSizeList->addItem(THREEpxIcon,QString("%1px").arg(i));
}
```

Or if you have different icons for each line:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 21 ; i++)
{
    penSizeList->addItem(QIcon(QString("iconLine%1.png").arg(i)),QString("%1px").arg(i));
}
```

If you want only icons, set empty string:

```
penSizeList->addItem(icon,"");
```

If you want full image then you should set this image as background. For example:

```
QPixmap pxmap("G:/2/qt.jpg");
QStandardItemModel *md = new QStandardItemModel;
QStandardItem *iii = new QStandardItem;
iii->setBackground(QBrush(Qt::red));
iii->setText("ss");
QStandardItem *iiii = new QStandardItem;
iiii->setBackground(QBrush(pxmap));
iiii->setText("ss");
md->setItem(1,0,iii);
md->setItem(0,0,iiii);
ui->comboBox->setModel(md);
```

Comment: Is there anyway we can get rid of the string,? because even with an empty string, it still pushes the icon to the left, and wont let it take the whole width of the row.

Comment: thank you @Chernobyl. one more question. Since we can use background colors for each row. Is there a way i can control the height of the background color for each row? so lets say in QComboBox the rows ranges from 1 to 20 , each row defining the thickness of a pen. so lets say the height of the background is 20 at its maximum. Row one would be 5% of the height of the Background ( so it sows a thin line ) Row 2 would be 10 % ( so it shows a thicker line) .... to row 20 -> 100% of the height ( the thickest line) ,

Comment: @AndreFarah No. QBrush is just show whole image. You should use images which you prepared earlier or you can try to draw it in app. Draw on Pixmap using QPainter which has a lot of options.